# approach to save and load a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, file-io, text-files

I need to save a 3D matrix in a text file that will be loaded in Matlab (which I don't master). My first idea was to do it with a .csv like this, (consider a 3x3x3 matrix):

```
        row 1: v[0][0][0],v[0][0][1] ,v[0][0][2]
        row 2: v[0][1][0],v[0][1][1] ,v[0][1][2]
        row 3: v[0][2][0],v[0][2][1] ,v[0][2][2]
        row4: v[1][0][0],v[1][0][1] ,v[1][0][2] 
        ...
```

Like this, I must inform the user separately about the number of x an y dimensions. Not too clean, but not a big drama.

My question is, how could I load and plot in Matlab a dataset like this? Values are 1/0.

Is there any smarter way of doing this. I am exporting from Java.

Thanks!

Comment: `dlmread` reads a 2D array. `reshape` can reshape it into 3D. If you wrote it in the correct order, it's a 1-line operation.

Comment: Just use `save` and `load`. `save` has a mode where it saves in text format if you must, but the default binary format is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way that you can omit storing the dimensions of the matrix (at least two of them should be mentioned). But when it comes to storing values in a file, I suggest that you do not bother to even write them in tabular format. All you need to know about MATLAB is the order of elements in a matrix. Take a look at this example:

```
%% create a 3d matrix
% a = 1+randi(5);
% b = 1+randi(5);
% c = 1+randi(5);
a = 2; b = 3; c = 4;
M = reshape(1:a*b*c, a, b, c)
```

This is how the matrix looks like:

> M(:,:,1) =
>
> ```
>  1     3     5
>  2     4     6
> ```
>
> M(:,:,2) =
>
> ```
>  7     9    11
>  8    10    12
> ```
>
> M(:,:,3) =
>
> ```
> 13    15    17
> 14    16    18
> ```
>
> M(:,:,4) =
>
> ```
> 19    21    23
> 20    22    24
> ```

Now let's write it in a text file:

```
%% writing matrix in the text file,
%  translate it to your target language
fid = fopen('matrix.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%d,%d,%d\n', a, b, c);
for k=1:c
    for j=1:b
        for i=1:a
            fprintf(fid, '%-.8g\n', M(i, j, k));
        end
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

This is the contents of the file:

> 2,3,4
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ...
> 21
> 22
> 23
> 24

Now, to read the file:

```
%% read the file back in MATLAB
fid = fopen('matrix.txt', 'r');
sz = str2num(fscanf(fid, '%s\n', 1)); % read dimensions
M2 = reshape(fscanf(fid, '%f\n', inf), sz); % read values
fclose(fid);

%% test the imported matrix
disp(sz)
if all(all(all(M == M2)))
    disp('OK')
else
    disp('Test failed.')
end
```

Comment: You don't need a loop, `fprintf(fid, '%-.8g\n', M)` will do the same thing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sure it does, but I thought that OP needs to implement that part in another language, and they said they're not familiar with matlab that much.

Comment: Super clear explanation! Thanks a lot for your time. :)